# How to place file in app directory via USB

Tags: android

I'm writing an app that reads from a local file

```
...
    File fXmlFile = new File(file);
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
...
```

I want to place the file into the app's directory so I can commence testing. Outputting the exception I find out that java.io.FileNotFoundException /data/data/com.blablabla.myApp/files/sample_file.xml: open failed. ENOENT (no such file or directory).

I'm confused as to where to find the directory /data/data/... I've connected the phone via USB and did find the /Android and /data directories. I've created my directory com.blablabla.myApp/files/ and added my sample_file.xml there but I continue getting the error.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `I've created my directory com.blablabla.myApp/files/ and added my sample_file.xml `. Please show full path of the file.

Comment: `new File(file);`. You did not show/tell what file is not its value.

Comment: `the /Android and /data directories.`. ???

Comment: I'm not creating the file in the app. I'm placing the file onto the device manually.

Comment: /Android and /data directories - http://imgur.com/gallery/KAPXR64/new This is what I'm talking about.

Comment: Yes you already told that. I know. Don't repeat that but answer the questions.

Comment: That is a nonsense picture. Which program do you use for that? And as it shows two places you did not tell which one you used. Is it with MTP protocol? That does not show you the real paths on the device.

Comment: I'm connected via USB so obviously I'm using my Windows file browser as I already stated. I've followed this approach with both directories.

Comment: Here's an example http://imgur.com/STymtBs

Comment: Is that data folder also contained in that Android folder?

Comment: Yes, I've done that as well.

Comment: No. No. You should not do that. Do not create a data folder. Why did you? Normally the Android folder contains already a data folder. Don't mess around with that. Don't tell me it did not contain a data folder.

Comment: It contained the /data folder but not the /data/data/..... structure. In /Android/ it did not contain my app's folder. So instead of telling me what not to do, let's focus on what needs to be done in order to get my objective accomplished please.

Comment: I am just trying to find out what unhappy things you did. But you donot seem to apreciate my efforts.

Comment: Quite frankly, who cares what folders I've temporarily setup. The question is where I place a file manually so the app can read it. Input such as "That is a nonsense picture" and "I am just trying to find out what unhappy things you did" are off the mark and not helpful.

Comment: Now, I understand that you're much smarter than me so I've provided the information I have available to me based on my understanding and availability. If there's a better way to do it please someone tell me and let's get this moving forward. This isn't helpful.

Comment: The content of the file variable is getFilesDir() + "/" + "sample_file.xml"

Comment: And which full path would that be?

Comment: /data/data/com.blablabla.myApp/files/sample_file.xml as outlined in my question.

Comment: If you see an Android directory with MTP on your windows pc than it is the Android directory which is part of getExternalFilesDir().  Please investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried looking for the file on internal storgage. Turns out that anything I can see when connected via USB/MTP protocol is the external storage. As such, I was unable to place the file where my read statement would find it. Making an adjustment where the app looks for the file made the difference.